# Длинное сложение

Tags: c, массивы

Даны числа `N`, `M`, `A`, `B`, где `N` - длина числа `A`, `M` - длина числа `B`.

Требуется найти и вывести сумму чисел `A` и `B`.

**Входные значения**

Со стандартного устройства ввода в первой строке вводятся числа `N (1 <= N <= 1000)` - длина числа `A` и `M (1 <= M <= 1000)` — длина числа `B`.

Во второй строке вводится число `A(1 <= A)`.

В третьей строке вводится число `B(1 <= B)`.

**Выходные значения**

Требуется найти и вывести сумму чисел `A` и `B`. Выводить пробел в конце строки не нужно.

**Пример входных данных**

17 17

56356356456456456

87987987897897980

**Пример выходных данных**

144344344354354430

Comment: **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Покажите код, мы его обязательно заставим работать. В вашем примере что-то странное: `(56356356456456456 + 87987987897897980) - 144344344354354430 = 6`

Comment: Выложите попытки решения задачи. Хоть что нибудь. Даже если не будет работать мы поможем, но вряд ли кто-то захочет с 0 вам все делать за так. Вообще задача же простая, обычное сложение в столбик реализуйте и все.

Comment: @ann Решил вашу задачу [вот мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1227523/267338), посмотрите!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учитывая небольшую длину (до 1000 цифр), я решил написать программу, которая складывает по-циферно (как в школьном алгоритме), в реальных библиотеках длинной арифметики складывают не по-циферно, а машинными словами (по 32 или 64 бита), для эффективности и скорости.

Благодаря по-циферному сложению не нужно даже переводить в двоичную форму числа, прямо символы и складываем.

[Попробовать онлайн!](https://tio.run/##hVJtb9pADP6eX2Fa0d6RMCWsGzBepiSqpqpKJtFNo2IIRXmBk@BASdC0rfx2Zl8SXlamRZfk7rEf24/PYTNcBnK@319HcSJkDDN39GX2dO9@Hd3P/M@zb/bIf/A/PYGlXQsZLrdRDP0sj8T6zWJ4BqVCzgnTqkjeg8/GBjxzYIyNOfQHwJ45h49Apw/qcHS2x2fOw0vOmpA5rAIhGYffGuBDgA8DMA3w6Ncr0ARYFgYyYVf1COrRd3llwI2Pr8ehNoAWvLwgrQ9WsRmCZZom7b0K9EqwSkTPBiXmGNMJIsBgXg3j8t7BnMb5NpXQtApop77hIkjBnlhm625qgFNt3GJTeK7iVRbnzDVIRiZ@xeuEubyMTAofUdoBhyaUGZJ5nGfMNlCBDi2k4rVIfmpzqC2vbKo9ebqMJbNVP4ivVJeoo1BiWv/SL7erDNB3ni8y7DAEkhpdU51mDP34IYOq@C/UKdD/dc@e@NPjtToT7@REjQmDNP15hJJ1CpQFBGKYckF/miy6LU5yemjCOVyIHui6OBVHtGy7QgJTLj6OHqbHKsUUP7fmLU6hSUEKu4d2LOiCXRV1FKa6jYFxoi20n6RU81EqsHpnMBGaRDjCO4iXWXyRfOLlTh6LklAHzR5XuXWqj7@ay3AtsxwasHHR3S3MPxZiGQOrNTYuP0TV9c25ucGQo8bj5gYaxB@oFBcY1dTUMzUcGLbAywvH2nfafm@1wWpr796/VeuuWlqn3VWr06XV7ZjaHw)

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MIN(X, Y) (((X) <= (Y)) ? (X) : (Y))
#define MAX(X, Y) (((X) >= (Y)) ? (X) : (Y))

int main() {
    int N = 0, M = 0;
    if (scanf("%d %d\n", &N, &M) != 2 || N < 1 || N > 1000 || M < 1 || M > 1000) {
        printf("Bad N, M!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    char A[1024], B[1024], C[1024];
    memset(C, 0, sizeof(C));
    int K = sizeof(C) - 1;
    fgets(A, N + 2, stdin);
    fgets(B, M + 2, stdin);
    if (strlen(A) != N + 1 || strlen(B) != M + 1) {
        printf("Bad nums lengths %d and %d!\n", ((int)strlen(A)) - 1, ((int)strlen(B)) - 1);
        return -1;
    }
    A[N] = 0;
    B[M] = 0;
    int carry = 0;
    for (int i = 1, hi = MAX(N, M) + 1; i <= hi; ++i) {
        int sum = (i <= N ? A[N - i] - '0' : 0) + (i <= M ? B[M - i] - '0' : 0) + carry;
        if (sum >= 10)  {
            carry = 1;
            sum -= 10;
        } else
            carry = 0;
        C[K - i] = (char)(sum + '0');
    }
    char const * pC = C;
    while (!*pC)
        ++pC;
    while (*(pC + 1) && *pC == '0')
        ++pC;
    printf("%s\n", pC);
    return 0;
}
```

Ввод:

```
17 17
56356356456456456
87987987897897980
```

Вывод:

```
144344344354354436
```

Comment: Хмм я думал сайт создан для того, чтобы помогать, а не делать за автора вопроса всю работу.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков В журналах с кроссвордами тоже в конце ответы дают, никто не заставляет использовать или смотреть ответ, если ещё не решил. А если не собираешься решать, тогда ничего плохого что посмотришь ответ, чему то хоть научишься. А если не знаешь как решить, то можешь подсмотреть программу-решение, и попробовать по памяти воспроизвести для закрепления.

Comment: Если бы автор хотел научится, он бы показал хоть какие нибудь свои знания через попытки решения. Мое мнение, что сайт вот такими вопросами скоро будет,  как площадка где бесплатно домашку делают, а не помогают разобраться.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Я считаю, если автор ответа сам хочет решить задачу, и задача ему нравится, то ничего плохого если он будет давать ответ. Если решения сделаны на энтузиазме, то вполне нормальный вариант если StackOverflow будет иногда сайтом решения домашних задач. Лишние знания не портят сайт.

Comment: Я для себя выделил несколько типов вопросов: 1) Где автор задает конкретный вопрос, прикрепляя свои решения и где видно, что автор хочет разобраться в проблеме 2) Вопрос в котором автор скидывает вот так условие и хотя бы, словами (без кода) пытается разобраться. 3) Вопрос в котором, автор без лишних слов скидывает условие задачи. И если на 2 тип еще можно помочь человеку, то 3 это очевидно, что автор просто скопирует и вставит код. "будет иногда сайтом решения домашних задач"?? Мне кажется вы сейчас сайт оскорбили. Есть куча сайтов, где решают подобные задачи и вообще все, что угодно.

Comment: @ПавелЕриков Не понимаю, чем лишние знания оскорбляют сайт? Мне кажется сервера хранить лишний миллион текстовых постов по 1КБ могут легко. То что я любой вопрос, даже простой могу найти на StackOverflow, а не идти на другие сайты, тоже плюс. То что StackOverflow может благодаря изобилию любых вопрос стать следующей википедией в области решения программистских задач, тоже большой бонус. То что интересно авторам ответов скоротать вечер за решением интересных задач, пусть даже не решённых, тоже вроде плюс. А то что автору вопроса не обязательно читать ответ если не хочет, тоже факт.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118072/discussion-between---and-arty).